# Create a class instance from data in an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, instance

I have a [full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS%20ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCC0sYgmEAElODp4OoUABvRQlEoESg6OooAD6nAZkHyV1QlE4zAA3DPZ-PdEvQKv2IhpN9N5wL1eyAfZ-MF6flwye6hN1Sd-vD3OXwoZ7cOwG5bj%20B5-milLbuwsDoGQSprsg%20TfsM-C3pe14YfeFxmlwn6obu-DARuhHMDq05Pk%20QyCAEq7rjy-Tro%20VElDRdHYd8jGcQ%20kHUWotFvnhqK8u%20%20Esax7HLiRjEkRJoAAL7BJBTo0EhkBKjqX7bhWlGsSWOb4pkAkccxkFKSpOb9He3yaTeNnYnprFOKgRkCIJPHyRZT6qWIwmoHZYG6Xxs4uW5UlidsXnBD5VkkYFZGgE5VFhSa7l0XJ5mKBZ7jpKO44WMIvIANqQclT7qZufLEGYeagAAso06gMHyvAhSUPGbgAjAAnD1ACsbX6X5H5VQAJF1AAMvAAByTZNrXtXCIFVV1ABMwCTf1wC9QNUpPgpQ2zuVs6VfyxB5gkTUtUdrGdaAa3zdNS2RZ%20-JjTNvBPYtw0katk3AAAzF1wCPfN%202zodZVLWdfLJhYYwVHot6QD9%20n3WDgO3VRr3jT1vD9eD2NPn9-KTQA7KDG2YxDJRQ0%20J0deuVU4Ow0ixBeGxo3dDndX15PE7OuPvV1AAsX1E0tpN8pNPWbSDu3k7TinY4zTHIfy4AUNwKDJkQXjEAQDCFdzVH3btn0vf543iwAbJLv0rWTINrZTFvK0pAC6EEQuKNDJFwcENF4qkjmOE6Ibz1mYWQWmgGHBUoAAPqAXA68kGSQK4yW5aAABWsqcMm0h54xGTh4VAQZzwSpLUq5eJzqPIAHw%20hXkABDxPLcryPGQTq8kIkqACEBeNMXed6sNqVeGPRcl-Jc8T4xE%20QHBAQMIOFDMJwSoJxOATzoMgztPwS8lwPkEz-nhcTweSklEAA) on the typescript website.  Basically, the last line in this function is not working

```
export function getInvoice(number: number): Invoice | undefined {
    let jsonObj = invoices.find(
        (invoice) => invoice.number === number
    );
    if(!jsonObj)
        return jsonObj;
    jsonObj = Object.assign(Invoice.prototype, jsonObj);
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Invoice is an array of objects including invoice data.  After I get the object back, I am trying to convert it into a typed Invoice object to use. The return `jsonObj` is erroring out for some reason with the error

```
TS2739: Type '{ name: string; number: number; amount: string; due: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Invoice': _name, _number, _amount, _due
```

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a `string`. (Objects are not JSON.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your example is a misuse of [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign): if you want an instance of the `Invoice` class, then create one:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=65&ssc=1&pln=70&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2A3A9gS2AU2gbwFDQOgAcAnVRMAFywH14wBbDALmgkrPgHMBufQ0uSq14AVwYAjDCVZjJ0voWJkK1aDUbJR8Sq3ade-AoNW0AJqJZsOqbnyPRgyePtHBKyEgAp6TZvtsuABpoOSkZMOkQzW1dAO4QixZ4rgBKPCUlSgALVAgAOjpGLABeUOLFTIIcvMLIkmgy+sqqmoKNBi0dRugYnRbMtsKknqSBgF9cKaUuDEpypi9UvRtuHAclEjnREnhoIaKmCenCWfn6pdlxcPWqgi3KHb2D5odJhzPeztjL6wNbu4PJ77XLtPqUY4fObQJK-FIAqpA3Yg2o0MZvXDvEDQ2wodAYGBlADaDgyd18VgARABlMA6MDQACyznQYEpQQ2hHqrAAjABOPkAVg5dy+XV00EpABIeQAGIIADllsvZnIISVYlJ5ACYAPSywW6-lCylvEWEMlVCma6mUOkAaxZbPNVuu0lY2uV8rVYtimqlCqCXtVoo1krluoAzDzdZ7laalOMXQjMtbJQB5TB06AAQUQGDEGBD5LdMmgccjyaU4P9fKCgvjVcIYcpsoA7LG9RWE4Qk6SfWnKQAVUQSHLiIjSYuu+Rl41tpsEGuSmUAFiDjZ9LdlfP1MfnPYIfaUltTxU1AHVUGYsOnJ3tqUQwJgINPU6XeQLAz7l9L1wA2TdQ0sTVZRjbUO2NBVD2gSYAF17AwAAPIhPHmAAzbR3FQZxoDOBA8UwLw7RIM4ADkP1CUtljgJA0EwaAAB9oG0G90NsDAzABJwXHmZAelxeiCXydj4DMLwvGwepxlSRoAD4qNnRoSjKEjyOoypUHQrwAEJkFkpE9lYjBRM4yoePYHBwUSSwQgpOzS3GHpkEqQzQgwAB3WjCIwHxigc2dom+HQbIwVI+EmIA)

```ts
export function getInvoice(targetNumber: number): Invoice | undefined {
  const o = invoices.find(({number}) => number === targetNumber);
  if(!o) return undefined;
  const {amount, due, name, number} = o;
  return new Invoice(name, number, amount, due);
}
```